# Database design affected by UI needs: Should I make an extra field or a new relation?

Tags: sql, database, erd

I have this relation:

*1 Incident Report has N Documents. The Incident Report could have a field like PupilName backed by a PupilID.*

**OR**

I could change the design to:

*1 Pupil has N Incident Reports etc...*

My concern is that I do not like the extra table because in my GUI I used a simple grouped

DataGrid for the Incident Reports. When I have now still a Pupil Entity just to display the

PupilsName in the grouped Header...and the Incident Reports below in the Datarow. Of course

that would not be possible as I can not display a 1:N relation in a DataGrid!

What would you do?

Answer (score 3):

Lisa, I see no design problems in the question.

```
 Pupil               IncidentReport               Document
+---------+         +------------------+         +------------------+
| PupilID |         | IncidentReportID |         | DocumentID       |
+---------+         +------------------+         +------------------+
| Name    | -|---<- | PupilID          | -|---<- | IncidentReportID |
| ...     |         | ...              |         | ...              |
+---------+         +------------------+         +------------------+
```

Although I may not quite understand the question.

Comment: Nice presentation of tables - it's good to see those posts that are cared for :-)

Comment: Concerning your drawings I also see no problem ;P seriously Paulo, the problem is I think its in my head lol I was too fast... I will put the Pupil and IncidentReport entity into ONE ViewModel so I can still use it in a grouped DataGrid because I do want to keep my UI as easy as possible. Do not want to introduce a TreeView to satisfy the 1:N relation needs. Hm I think I will delete this question. Now solution is needed :) But concerning JamWaffles post yeah you put a lot of work in those tables I like them, those are worth a point at least ;-)

Comment: Lisa, there's no need to add a Tree View for such thing. remember that you can create a database view to integrate the relation and present the data in a tabular manner while retaining the normalization of the underlieing tables.

Comment: @Paulo I do not deal with database views for this purpose ("Composite UI") I use the MVVM design pattern. Above all Views cost performance on the server I prefer to build my "View" in the code :)

Comment: This assumes each Incident can only involve one pupil. That seems odd.

Comment: @Pau Yes and No... : there is nothing about involved to keep it simple and realistic like I experience it at school. Each Pupil can have Many IncidentReports. Take this scenario: There are many pupils which smack down ONE pupil. The victim gets NO incident report, why should it? Now we have many offender. Every of them gets a new incident report with individual description what they have done and what action we have undertaken to prevent such a situtation again etc... So there is no N:M its a 1 : N relation. No Incident Report can belong to more than ONE pupil :)